# ASP.NET :: Merging distinct from one column and sum from others

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
|  ID  | Name |Parm1 |Parm2 |Parm3 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|   1  |Type1 |   1  |   2  |   3  |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|   2  |Type2 |   2  |   3  |   4  |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|   3  |Type1 |   3  |   2  |   4  |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

ID is the PK (nvarchar(50)),
Name is a string (nvarchar(MAX)),
and the parametes are numbers vary from 1 to 4 (int).

I would like to have a distinc name column and sum the other cells, like this:
* The ID column is not needed.

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Name |Parm1 |Parm2 |Parm3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|Type1 |   4  |   4  |   7  |
+------+------+------+------+
|Type2 |   2  |   3  |   4  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Makes no difference if I either do it by editing a data table in my code, or by an SQL query.

Any help would be appreciated..!

Comment: try `SELECT Name, SUM(Parm1), SUM(Parm2), SUM(Parm3)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're query will use a simple `GROUP BY`:

```
select Name, SUM(Parm1) as Parm1, SUM(Parm2) as Parm2, SUM(Parm3) as Parm3
from mytable
group by Name
```

Comment: I did not make my self clear enough, because I also needed to use a where clause for a number of variables...but with that query and some code I managed to solve the problem...;)  Thank You!